linux shared memory doesn't showed as expect
I use mmap create a shared memory, two process shared the memory. I use the 'top' command to watch the shared memory output, it looks like:
1825191 root      20   0   10972     88      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 a.out                                                                                                                                                           
1825190 root      20   0   10972    964    876 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 a.out  

The process 1825190 is parent process, the shared memory for it is 876K. The 1825191 is child process which is forked from the parent process(1825190). The shared memory for it is zero.
It's confusing, base on my understanding, the shared memory in the child process should also be 876K. Because the parent process and child process is complete same.
Another strange thing is the memory account in the Linux proc system. In the path
/proc/1825190/status

RssAnon:              88 kB
RssFile:             876 kB
RssShmem:              0 kB

I think my code is directly mapped from the memory, why does the RssShmem not reflect the shared memory size?
Another confusing point about shared memory, below is the memory region in the process, I think for the processes, the memory should complete the same for the parent process and child process because they are the same memory area. But sometimes, the Shared_Dirty and Shared_Clean between the parent process and child process aren't the same, does anyone know what's the cause?
VmFlags: rd wr mr mw me ac 
7f7bbe893000-7f7bbf093000 rw-s 00000000 00:01 5130                       /dev/zero (deleted)
Size:               8192 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Rss:                   4 kB
Pss:                   2 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          4 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:         0 kB
Referenced:            4 kB
Anonymous:             0 kB
LazyFree:              0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FilePmdMapped:         0 kB
Shared_Hugetlb:        0 kB
Private_Hugetlb:       0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
SwapPss:               0 kB
Locked:                0 kB
THPeligible:    0


Below is my code, does it have some issues?
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>  // for wait()

int main() {
    // Size of the shared memory region
    size_t mem_size = 1024 * 4096 * 2;

    // Create an anonymous shared memory region
    void *shared_mem = mmap(NULL, mem_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    if (shared_mem == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Initialize shared memory with some data
    strcpy((char *)shared_mem, "Hello from parent process!");

    // Fork a child process
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork failed");
        munmap(shared_mem, mem_size);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (pid == 0) {
        // Child process
        printf("Child: Shared memory contains: '%s'\n", (char *)shared_mem);

        // Modify the shared memory
        strcpy((char *)shared_mem, "Hello from child process!");
        printf("Child: Modified shared memory.\n");

        // Sleep for demonstration purposes
        sleep(600);

        // Exit child process
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    } else {
        // Parent process
        // Sleep for a while to let the child modify the memory
        sleep(5);

        // Read and print the modified content
        printf("Parent: Shared memory contains: '%s'\n", (char *)shared_mem);


        sleep(600);

        // Wait for the child process to finish
        wait(NULL);

        // Unmap shared memory
        munmap(shared_mem, mem_size);

        printf("Parent: Finished.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

